# Converting a structured address into a single line, skipping empty parts

Tags: c#

I'm having a senior moment...
I have a class like the following

```
public class Client
{
   public DomainObjects.FullAddress FullAddress { get; set; }
   public string AddessLine {
      get 
      { 
         return string.Format(FullAddress.Address + ", " + 
                              FullAddress.Address2 + ", " +
                              FullAddress.Town); 
      }
   }
}
```

How do I improve my `AddressLine`, for example if any of the properties of `FullAddress` is Empty, dont return that property
So I would not want: 223, , Town

But formatted like: 223, Town

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullAddress.Address) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx

Comment: See the method you have in the String class, I guess it must have one which can replace ",," by ",".. For example: `return "223,,Town".replace(",,", ",");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use combination of `string.Join` and treat those values as filtered collection:

```
var values = new[] { FullAddress.Address, FullAddress.Address2, FullAddress.Town };
var result = string.Join(", ", values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

And if it is a common operation in your code, you can create a helper class like:

```
class StringExtensions
{
    public static string JoinNonEmpty(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
    }

    public static string JoinNonEmpty(string separator, params object[] values)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.ToString())));
    }
}
```

then your property will be:

```
public string AddressLine {
   get 
   { 
      return StringExtensions.JoinNonEmpty(", ", FullAddress.Address, 
                                           FullAddress.Address2,
                                           FullAddress.Town); 
   }
}
```

It has additional advantage of not creating an additional temporary class of values to join.

Comment: Youi forgot the separator in your `StringExtensions.JoinNonEmpty` sample

Comment: This gives a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Exception in cases where any 1 of the values in `values` is `null`, at this statement => `return string.Join(separator, values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.ToString())));`

Comment: Suggest IsNullOrWhiteSpace in place of IsNullOrEmpty given the original question.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to test each value with [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx), then use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to separate with commas:

```
var fields = new List<string>();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FullAddress.Address))
    fields.Add(FullAddress.Address)

...

return string.Join(", ", fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Client
{
    public DomainObjects.FullAddress FullAddress { get; set; }
    public string AddessLine
    {
        get
        {
            return Address();
        }
    }

    private string Address()
    {
        string address = string.Empty;

        address += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullAddress.Address) ? FullAddress.Address + ", " : string.Empty;
        address += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullAddress.Address) ? FullAddress.Address2 + ", " : string.Empty;
        address += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullAddress.Address) ? FullAddress.Town + ", " : string.Empty;

        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why it is not `Down Voted`. But still using `+` will lead to lot of `garbage`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version, But I would go with Konrad's version.

```
return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
  FullAddress.Address, FullAddress.Address2, FullAddress.Town)
  .Replace(", ,", ",").TrimEnd(new[] {' ' , ',' });
```